# Is it possible to set a colour by variable?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I'm developing an application in VB.net with WPF and I would like the end-user to be able to change the colors of the application from the settings page.

This is a snippet of the XAML I have for one of the vector paths:
[image]

Bear in mind, all my icons are vectors so there are around 4410 lines of XAML. My thinking is to set the HEX code to a variable and in the VB code, I can set the variable to something like "FFF15329":

[image]

Is something like this possible? I am more than happy to go through and set the existing HEX codes to variables or something else.

Comment: And this XAML is for... WPF? Silverlight? UWP? Xamarin? MAUI? XAML is XML, so you could always read it into an XDocument using LINQ to XML...

Comment: Sorry, I am using WPF, I have edited the question to include this :)

Comment: I don't think you should store that color in the XAML, rather in a settings file which will be read at runtime

Comment: How would the XAML read from the settings file? Also, would the VB code be able to modify the settings files?

Comment: There is a wealth of information on Google: *wpf change control color at runtime*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF: Changing Resources (colors) from the App.xaml during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786183/wpf-changing-resources-colors-from-the-app-xaml-during-runtime)

Comment: @MakAhmed I just tested that, I can set the color in XAML to "BackgroundColor" which is yellow, But I try to set the color with this: Application.Current.Resources("BackgroundColor") = "Blue", which doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to use your code because you had given it as image,, but it will be like below example, replace your Path Fill Color with Dependency-Property and then set this Dependency-Property from your Main Window

### Custom Control -- HeaderButton

```
<Grid>
    <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderThickness="2" 
            Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HeaderButton},Mode=FindAncestor},Path=BackgroundColor}">
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

### Code Behind

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(BackgroundColor),typeof(string),typeof(HeaderButton),new PropertyMetadata("Transparent"));

    public string BackgroundColor
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(BackgroundColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty,value);
    }
```

### Mainindow.xaml

```
<local:HeaderButton Width="100" Height="100" BackgroundColor="Red" />
```